# How to multiply two Sparse matrices by Spars method with python?

Tags: numpy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication, numpy-ndarray, python-3.8

I tried to multiply the two Sparse matrices, but I had trouble deleting extra rows that were all zeros, I used`numpy.delete(my_matrix, [n], axis=0)`and got this error:

**index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3**

```
def mult_mat(mat1, mat2):
col = mat1[0][1]
row = mat2[0][0]
row_mat1, row_mat2 = np.shape(mat1)[0], np.shape(mat2)[0]
if col != row:
    return "Multiplication is not possible because the number" \
           " of columns in the first matrix is opposite of the" \
           " number of rows in the second matrix"
my_matrix = np.array([[0] * 3] * (mat1[0][2] * mat2[0][2]))
n = 0
for r in range(1, row_mat1):
    for h in range(1, row_mat2):
        if mat1[r][1] == mat2[h][0]:
            my_matrix[n][0], my_matrix[n][1], my_matrix[n][2] = mat1[r][0], mat2[h][1], mat1[r][2] * mat2[h][2]
            n += 1
row_my_matrix = np.shape(my_matrix)[0]
for n in range(row_my_matrix):
    if my_matrix[n][0] == 0 & my_matrix[n][1] == 0 & my_matrix[n][2] == 0:
        my_matrix = np.delete(my_matrix, [n], axis=0)
return my_matrix
```

Comment: Just use basic debugging methods.  Isolate the problem set of lines, and figure out the correction.  Keep in mind that as you delete rows the array shrinks, and valid indexes change.  Also consider finding the rows to delete, but doing the actual delete just once.

Comment: A simpler case.  Delete 0s from `[0,1,,1,0,1]`